# How is app binary submitted for an expedited review request?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have filled the form for an expedited review, I am yet to submit the form. How is the binary suppose to be uploaded? should it be done as normal, before the expedited review form is submitted or after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apple page on iTunes connect says this

> If you've submitted an update to fix a critical bug in your app on the App Store and you are requesting an expedited review...

This appears to suggest that the app must be submitted first, and then the expedite request can be issued.

Answer (score 2):

Submit your app for review as usual.  Then submit form requesting expedited review.